# Undo the last click on button using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I have a code like this -

```
<button class="btn">New York</button>
<button class="btn">Amsterdam</button>
<button class="btn">New Jersey</button>
<button class="btn">Alabama</button>
<button class="btn">Michigan</button>
<button id="undo" class="undo-selection">Undo last selection</button>
```

and have below code to check the order at which these buttons are clicked.

```
var click = 0;
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.btn');
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var current = button.innerText;
    var existingClicks = current.split(" ");
    if(existingClicks.length > 1) {
      button.innerText += ` & ${++click}`;
    }
    else {
      button.innerText = `clicked = ${++click}`;
    }
  });
});
```

By using the Undo button I want to clear last selection made and should be able to select new button. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not a trivial problem to solve. You would need to store the indexes of the buttons as they are clicked, an array is an obvious choice for this. Then you can `pop()` elements from that array when the undo button is clicked. The tricky part will be that you need to rebuild all the buttons states when the array is updated. Also note that your logic is flawed due to the use of `.split(" ")` to detect when there is an existing click - `New York` and `New Jersey` both count as already being clicked due to the space they contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```js
let click = 0;
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.btn');
const clicks = [];
buttons.forEach((button, index) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    const clicked = clicks.includes(index);
    clicks.push(index);
    if (!clicked) {
      button.innerText = `clicked = ${++click}`;
    } else {
        button.innerText += ` & ${++click}`;
    }
  });
});

document.getElementById('undo').addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!clicks.length) {
    return;
  }
    const lastClicked = clicks.pop();
  click--;
  let text = buttons[lastClicked].innerText.split('&');
  text.pop();
  text = text.join('&');
  buttons[lastClicked].innerText = text || buttons[lastClicked].getAttribute('data-text');
});
```

```html
<button class="btn" data-text="New York">New York</button>
<button class="btn" data-text="Amsterdam">Amsterdam</button>
<button class="btn" data-text="New Jersey">New Jersey</button>
<button class="btn" data-text="Alabama">Alabama</button>
<button class="btn" data-text="Michigan">Michigan</button>
<button id="undo" class="undo-selection">Undo last selection</button>
```